# Spring context not loading context file

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, applicationcontext

I am creating a spring based web project and my files are as follows.
applicationContext.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd          
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="<package>" />

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value><package name></value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">update</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location">
            <value>classpath:<filename>.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

web.xml

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Here is the error i am getting when tomcat is started ,

```
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
May 10, 2016 6:40:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Could not load properties; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/<filename>.properties]
```

As the applicationContext.xml is not initialized , spring is not initializing the beans and i am unable to use those beans . Please help. Also why context loader is trying to load incorrect file ?

FYI , i am using spring 4.1.6.Release. Also this is is a maven project.

**EDIT**
So that issue is fixed after ike's suggestion to add classpath to place holder file. But still spring context is not yet initialized. Autowired attributes are still null . But as per the log , spring tried to connect mysql using sessionfactory mentioned in context file.

Tomcat deployment log.

```
    INFO: validateJarFile(E:\Development\Eclipse\Workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\tripmidas\WEB-INF\lib\javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
May 10, 2016 7:14:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
May 10, 2016 7:14:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Tue May 10 19:14:27 IST 2016 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Tue May 10 19:14:29 IST 2016 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Tue May 10 19:14:30 IST 2016 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
May 10, 2016 7:14:32 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig init
```

**EDIT 2**
Services class

```
@Path("/cities")
public class CityServices {

    @Autowired
    CityDAO cityDAO;

    @POST
    @Path("/search")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response searchCities(String inputJsonString)
    {
        if ( inputJsonString != null )
        {
            JSONObject inputJson = new JSONObject();
            try {
                inputJson = new JSONObject(inputJsonString);
                if ( !inputJson.has("keyword"))
                {
                    return Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity("Bad request").build();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity("Bad request").build();
            }

            String searchQuery = inputJson.getString("keyword");

            List<City> cities = cityDAO.searchCities(searchQuery);

            return Response.status(Status.OK).entity(cities).build();               
        }
        else {
            return Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity("Bad request").build();
        }
    }
}
```

DAO interface

```
public interface CityDAO {
    public List<City> searchCities(String searchQuery);
}
```

DAO Impl class

```
@Repository

    public class CityDAOImpl implements CityDAO {

        @Autowired
        private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        @Transactional
        public List<City> searchCities(String searchQuery) {
            Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
            Query query = session.createQuery("from "+ City.class.getName() + " where "
                    + "city_name like '%"+searchQuery+"%' OR city_airline_code like '%"+searchQuery+"%'");
            return query.list();
        }
    }
```

Context base package tag -

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com._._.dao" />
```

com.*.*.dao is the package where CityDAO is . Getting null pointer exception
at `List<City> cities = cityDAO.searchCities(searchQuery);` which means autowiring is not happening .

**EDIT 3**
Adding @Component annotation to the jersey service class resolved the issue :)

Thanks @ike3 for the help.

Comment: `Could not load properties; ... Could not open ... [/<filename>.properties]`. It seems you have PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer with <filename>.properties somewhere else in the spring config?

Comment: @ike3 Yes ! Its there. But why context load listener is trying to read that file instead of application context file ?

Comment: Yes. You are correct . As i have given <filename>.properties in context.xml , it is checking for that file in root directory , but it is there in WEB-INF/classes/<filename>.properties. So should i give this path is there any option to load that file from classpath ?

Comment: Try to change it to `classpath:/<filename>.properties`

Comment: @ike3 Thanks :) . Can you please check the edit i added now ?

Comment: Where are the autowired variables? Maybe the beans are in a package other than `base-package="<package>"` or the class with the variables is not a spring bean.

Comment: @ike3 Edits added. Please check.